# How to make text with certain id show up after hovering over a certain image

Tags: css

Okay so I have an image,

```
<div class="column">
<img src="images/picture.jpg" id="first" title="firstpic">
<span id="firstspan">This is what should appear when hovering over first image</span>
</div>
```

Now, how do I make it so that "firstspan" only shows up when someone hovers over the "first" image? Here is what I tried for the css.

```
#firstspan {
    display: none;
}

#first:hover #firstspan {
    display: block;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any idea on what is wrong?

Also, is there a way for #first to be positioned inside the image on the bottom? Rather than outside the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
img#first:hover ~ #firstspan {
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ZLj2G/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an effect on my code for some reason :s

Comment: Why not ? check the demo and copy paste the exact thing.

Comment: Okay perfect, yes the demo works perfectly, I just retyped my code and css and it worked, im guessing I forgot to just add a } in the css somewhere I guess, it was messing everything up. Thanks!

Comment: @user216485, Glad to know that (Hope you know how to accept the answer, by clicking the tick) welcome :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
.column:hover #firstspan {
    display: block;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XWkYJ/)

Comment: The image randomly starts continuously flickering :s Give me a few minutes, i'm going to go through the entire code and see why it's doing this.

Comment: Okay perfect, this works as well! I just retyped my code and css and it worked, im guessing I forgot to just add a } in the css somewhere I guess, it was messing everything up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't work because your image tag and span tag are siblings.  Your rule is looking for a parent to descendant relationship.

If you can wrap your image tag and span tag in a DIV and move the id for the image tag to this new container DIV your CSS should work.

```html
<div id="first">
     <img>
     <span id="firstspan"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try like this:

<div class="column">
<img src="images/picture.jpg" id="first" title="firstpic">
<span id="firstspan"> your text </span>
</div>

#firstspan {
    display: none;
}

.column:hover #firstspan{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes i am, But you should have asked this question before editing. I could have better explanation.